# Плавное увеличения толщины буквы

Tags: javascript, html, css

В документации написано

```
font-weight: bold|bolder|lighter|normal|100|200|300|400|500|600|700|800|900
```

Как обычно анимацию можно сделать через setInterval и в этом случаи увеличением с 100 до 900 свойство.
Но что-то, даже если я просто меняю средствами css, эти цифры не работают.

НА JavaScript. кроссбраузерно.

Comment: @andrey3, для отображения сам шрифт должен поддерживать все эти градации, иначе будет выбираться ближайшее значение.

Comment: посмотрите гугл фонт - как пример Open Sans

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3SmKq/

Comment: @soledar10 спасибо, но шрифт не совсем. У меня  "Helvetica", "Arial", "FreeSans", "Verdana", "Tahoma", "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Luxi Sans", sans-serif;

Comment: Смотрите ответ ниже - не все шрифты поддерживают такие градации, поэкспериментируйте с text-shadow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для работы этих цифр нужны соответствующие начертания выбранного шрифта. Большинство же, даже системных шрифтов, обладают лишь начертаниями с жирностью 400 и 700 (normal и bold). Сравните, например Open Sans и PT Sans на google.com/fonts

Как вариант - подключить все возможноные начертание Open Sans или любого другого шрифта с большим количеством "жирностей" к странице. Вопрос только в том надоли оно ради лишь эффекта.

Может быть попробуете поиграть с text-shadow?

Comment: Кстати надо иметь в виду что сопоставление числовых значений жирности, и названий начертаний (light, regular/normal, bold) зависит исключительно от воли левой пятки создателя шрифта. Начертания могут называться как угодно (есть некоторые традиции, но не более) и им могут соответсовавать любые цифровые значения. Полагаться можно разве-что на то что большее значение соответствует более жирному начертанию.